# Consequences of disabling the courier mail service on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, courier

For a while now I've been getting logwatch reports that indicate bots/scripts are trying to login with POP3 on my server. However I have not set this up, and am not using it as far as I'm aware (using Gmail MX).

Is it save to stop running the courier-service, or are other services (perhaps postfix, logwatch or sendmail) dependend on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a service like courier-pop or any other service, it will be always a good idea to disable it especially for publicly-accessible machines. This provides more security (less running services/opened ports) and less resources usage.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking the same. I do know non the domains on the server have MX records configured to this server (they do elsewhere). Can I safely disable courier-pop in that case? Or might sendmail or PHP be relient on this for some reason?

Comment: @Björn: sendmail is related to SMTP and it is not related to POP. If you are not using this machine for accessing your email inbox, then you can safely disable it.

Comment: Okay thanks, great to hear I don't need it :)

Comment: You need local mail delivery - just disabling Courier compromises the functionality / security your system - you need to replace it with a local MDA such as deliver / procmail

Comment: @symcbean: Hmm okay.. so it's a bit more complicated.. when Googling I found this: http://www.bloovis.com/wordpress/?p=176 is that a good replacement?

Comment: No - I didn't say replace the MTA - just change the MDA

Comment: @symcbean: Ah okay, could you perhaps write your solution as an answer and explain how to do this? I'm not that savvy with this..